# What form is the complex Jordan form allowed to take?

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

[image]

Could you please explain to me why is the last matrix not included in $(5.32)$?

How is the last matrix different form the three matrices in $(5.32)$.

Comment: The last matrix after a change of basis using $S$ as shown gives the second matrix

Comment: The JNF is unique up to permutation of the rows. It is then uninteresting to include the final matrix, as, by virtue of $S$ for example, it is equivalent to the matrix in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the matrices$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&0\\0&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\0&\lambda&1\\0&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}\tag1$$are similar (the author proved that) and therefore, if we want to have all types of matrices which are of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&\varepsilon_1&0\\0&\lambda&\varepsilon_2\\0&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$(with each $\varepsilon_j$ equal to $0$ or to $1$) such that every $3\times3$ matrix whose only eigenvalue is $\lambda$ is similar to one of them, it is redundant to have both matrices $(1)$.

Comment: Is it correct that the first matrix has three jordan blocks, the second has two blocks and the third has only one block (the entire matrix)?

Comment: @gbd Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan normal forms are only unique up to reordering of the blocks. Thus, the last matrix is the same Jordan normal form as the second in (5.32); i.e. if one is a Jordan normal form of a given matrix, so is the other.